# What terminates reading input into an int

Tags: c++

I'm studying C++ using the book : Programming principles and practice using C++. At the end of chapter 3 the author ask what terminates reading input into an int, I thought that the reading of input into an input terminated when you enter a whitespace just like the string type but after writing this program I have some doubts :

```
constexpr double cm_per_inch = 2.54; 
double lenght = 1; 

char unit = 0; 
cout << "Please enter a lenght followed by a unit (c or i):\n"; 
cin >> lenght >> unit; 

if (unit == 'i')
cout << lenght << "in == " << cm_per_inch * lenght << "cm\n";

else
cout << lenght << "cm == " << lenght / cm_per_inch << "in\n";
```

Here if I enter the input 1i cin will read 1 into lenght and i into unit, why ? shouldn't I use a whitespace to terminate reading into an int ? What's wrong ?

Comment: it'd come down to more what the OS treats as an input termination. cin's just going to pass control on down to the os's input mechanisms, and wait for an EOL character of some sort. e.g. carriage return

Comment: I'm guessing what was meant was given input in the input buffer, what causes a stop in going through the buffer, rather than what causes the input you enter to actually be given to the program.

Comment: Formatted extraction from a stream usually stops at white space characters or at 'incompatible' characters ('i' is not a numeric).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The >> operator on cin knows the type of the variable that it is attempting to extract and parse.  In your case, cin reads from standard input as long as the bytes extracted continue making up an integer.  As soon as any non-integer character is encountered, cin is done reading in the integer.  The barriers that determine when parsing is done varies depending on what type of variable you are attempting extract through the >> operator on cin.  num_get::get is what the >> operator on cin internally calls to parse variables based on the format expected.

Here is a link to a reference about the >> operator that cin implements (it goes into lots of detail): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

Comment: This is wrong: `These "sentries" vary depending on what type of variable you are attempting extract through the >> operator on cin.`

Comment: The behavior of a sentry varies depending on what datatype is being extracted.

Comment: Regarding sentry: Have a look at 27.7.2.1.3 (C++11)

Comment: Thank you, Dieter.  I misused the term "sentry".  num_get::get is what parses based on expected datatype.  I have edited answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

The input stream mechanism delimits input not only on whitespace or the end-of-file, but for whatever character doesn't match the formatting requirements for the type being read into. When you use the `>>` operator on an integer, the stream delegates the formatting to a "facet" class that contains information specific for handling the formatting for `int`s. When the facet finds a character that can't go into a integer, it stops reading and stores whatever's been read so far in the integer being read.

Answer (score 1):

To terminate a string-input you need *whitespace*, which is a *space*, *newline* or *tabulator*.
(See page 64)

To terminate a double you can type in anything that is not a valid double value.
(See page 121)

To terminate a loop you need a *end-of-input* character:
Windows: [Ctrl] + [Z]
Linux: [Ctrl] + [D]
(See page 72)

Answer (score 1):

Input into a string is terminated by whitespace, that is, space, newline, and tab characters.
Input into an integer is terminated by any non-numeric character.

Comment: This is suspiciously similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45485476/4283581